# Test variables INSIDE a view function - no return

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm new to Django + Python so I'm not sure how much of this question will make sense.

Basically, I'm working on a project (not created by me) that has a function within a views.py file. The purpose of this view function is not to give a HTTP response but to send an email.

It accepts a request as a parameter (which contains data that will be looped through - some of it being inserted into the email.

The end of the function does a call to an email_extrals.utils function send_mail_template(various different variables passed in).

My issue is that I want to write a test for this function which essentially returns nothing (that I can see - it just sends an email). This view function is actually called elsewhere in an API.

The purpose of this test is to ensure that if certain variables are present in the request data, then they should be present in a variable which gets passed to the send_email_template() call. So I'm kind of testing for variables inside the function - not what gets returned.

I need a way of somehow accessing the internal variables of the function to test them.

I can't think of a way to test this and at this point I'm banging my head against a wall. Any test info I can find online for views is mainly just testing responses or various model related issues.

Any push in the right direction would be a huge help. A link to docs or a basic example of something similar.

Thanks, 
Dean

Comment: I'd probably create a second function that the 1st one calls that takes a request and returns everything needed to send the email and then test that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to make your own fake version of `send_email_template()` that does nothing except verify that it was called with the desired argument values, and raises an exception if they are wrong.

Then, in your test setup, you would *replace* the real `send_email_template()` with your fake one.  This is called [Mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

And just to be safe you would also want to assert that your fake function was *actually called*.

Comment: You sir, are a gent! Thank you very much.